# Deploy on AWS ElasticBeanstalk - run custom npm script before starting server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to deploy my nuxt universal app onto AWS elastic beanstalk. I've tried using custom npm script in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
 "dev": "nuxt",
 "build": "nuxt build",
 "start": "nuxt start",
 "generate": "nuxt generate",
 "precommit": "npm run lint",
 "deploy": "nuxt build && nuxt start"
},
```

Then under AWS EB config, i added Node command: npm run deploy

However, it is not working.

Basically, i need to tell EB to run "npm run build" before "npm run start"

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 3):

What you've described lies in the npm realm, and can be solved by using a prestart script, like so:

```
"prestart": "nuxt build"
```

More details here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right way to solve this.... Anytime the server restarts, it will have to rebuild first.  There should be some way to run it only after EB deploy and before start

Answer (score 1):

So far this has helped me, it seems to work for default nuxt project (nuxt create) in universal mode.
I am using Elastic Beanstalk, CodePipeline and Bitbucket.
CodePipeline takes code from Bitbucket once it is pushed and builds in on Elastic Beanstalk.

What helped me is adding to package.json:

```
"deploy": "npm run build && npm run start"
```

or

```
 "deploy": "npm run install && npm run build && npm run start"
```

and creating `Procfile` in root directory of project, content/command of Pocfile triggers the deploy script in package.json file

```
web: npm run deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Before, there were "hooks" but now they're almost deprecated https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html

Now you can use Buildfile and Procfile as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Comment: Have you found that Buildfile is supported on the AWS Linux 2 Node.js platform? We've been struggling with the same issue as the OP and found that Procfile is supported, but, and it's not super clear in the docs, Buildfile does not appear to be supported. From the docs: "Each individual platform topic specifically mentions Buildfile and/or Procfile if the platform supports them." The Node.js platform only specifically mentions Procfile.

We've found hooks to be unsatisfactory as they aren't called again on environment updates, even though the app seems to get undeployed.

Comment: It seems like "Custom platform hooks" are deprecated, but "Platform hooks" are not. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html and the Node.js environment doesn't seem to support Buildfile.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding to your .ebextensions a "source_compile.config" file as follows:

```
# source_compile.config
container_commands:
  compile:
    command: "./node_modules/.bin/nuxt build"
    env:
      PATH: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.16.3-linux-x64/bin/
```

Got the idea from the same need to pre compile a typescript nodejs server before deploying to Elastic Beanstalk :)
Here a ref:

https://medium.com/@lhviet88/deploy-a-typescript-expressjs-into-elasticbeanstalk-nodejs-server-8381e00e7e52